# Line integral $\int_{\gamma}e^x\cos(y)dx+e^x\sin(y)dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

First of all, I'm having trouble evaluating $$∫_{γ}e^x\cos\left(y\right)dx+e^x\sin\left(y\right)dy$$ where $γ$ is the triangle with vertices $\left(0,0\right), \left(1,0\right), \left(1,\fracπ2\right)$

This is what I've done so far:

**1)** With Green's theorem:

$$∫_{γ}e^x\cos\left(y\right)dx+e^x\sin\left(y\right)dy=\iint_D2e^x\sin\left(y\right)dydx=∫_0^1∫_0^{\frac π 2 x}2e^x\sin\left(y\right)dydx$$

**2)** Using regular line integration: as $F=\left(e^x\cos\left(y\right), e^x\sin\left(y\right)\right)$

$$∫_{γ}e^x\cos\left(y\right)dx+e^x\sin\left(y\right)dy=$$
$$∫_0^1F\left(t,0\right)\left(1,0\right)dt+∫_0^{\frac π 2} F\left(1,t\right)\left(0,1\right)+∫_1^0F\left(t,\fracπ2t\right)\left(1,\fracπ2\right)$$
$$∫_0^1e^t+∫_0^{\frac π 2}e\sin\left(t\right)+∫_1^0e^t\cos\left(\fracπ2t\right)+e^t\sin\left(\fracπ2t\right)\fracπ2$$

I've computed both in wolfram, and they are different. They shouldn't! I don't get why. If someone could please explain me where I went wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Secondly, are those the only two methods we can use in order to evaluate a line integral? I mean, if I have a line integral, then it's either Green or regular integration right?

Finally, when we use the formula $∫_{γ}F=∫ F\left(γ\left(t\right)\right)γ'\left(t\right)dt$, are we assuming that the curve is positively oriented?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What values do you get in WolframAlpha? That's an important portion of the work you've tried so far.

Comment: @Semiclassical 7.322 for the second one, and 1.55 for the first one. It makes no sense! I've checked the domains and the theorem is valid. I don't get what did I do wrong!

Comment: I believe your limits of integration are incorrect, for the inner integral, it should be $0$ to $\pi x/2$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Superabound Yes, I'm sorry, I type it wrong. In my notes it's correct, so the problem is still the same

Comment: @ReneSchipperus you are talking about the third term in the second attempt right? I believe the limits are correct

Comment: @LunaSage Yes I just noticed it

Comment: Have you done the integrals yourself, this may give you a clue as to the problem.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'm solving them right now. I think the problem is in the parametrization if the second one, or when I computed the second one in WolframAlpha. If I come to any conclution, I'll let you know. I still have the second doubt though, are those the only possible methods?

Comment: I think those are the only general methods, unless there are some special circumstances, like symmetry.